# How to run a two-dimensional variable loop in bash?

Tags: bash

I want to run a two-dimensional for loop in bash, where the first index `i` goes from 1 to `n`, and the second index `j` runs from `1` to `i-1`. How can I do this?

So far, I was able to write a for loop where the second index `j` runs from `1` to `i`:

```
for i in $(seq 1 $n); do
    for j in $(seq 1 $i); do
        ...
    done
done
```

How do I make `j` go until `i-1` instead? What's the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use BASH's arithmetic construct `((...))`:

```
for ((i=1; i<=n; i++)); do
    for ((j=1; j<=i; j++)); do
        echo "$i:$j"
    done
done
```

Comment: To make `j go until i-1` you can do: `for ((j=1; j<i; j++)); do`

Comment: This will be more efficient: it does not have to call out to `seq` n+1 times.

Comment: Technically, this is not the arithmetic compound command; it's just the syntax for the C-style loop (which was presumably chosen because it *looks* like the arithmetic command, and variables are evaluated in an arithmetic context). `((i=1; i<=n; i++))` is not a valid arithmetic command on its own, as the semicolon separator is unique to the `for` statement.